# Typescript: Property type wildcard

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a given interface which comes from another package, so I can't really change it. For the sake of simplicity, let's just say the following interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
   someProp: string;
   someOtherProp?: number;
}
```

I was wondering if I can somehow extract the types of **all** properties so I would get a combined type which could be any of the original Interface's properties.

In the example, it would resolve to a type being `string | number | undefined`.

Also, not really the same question, but quite related to it. Is it possible to extract the allowed properties **names** instead of values, so in the example given it would be a type holding the values `"someProp" | "someOtherProp"`.

For the first case, I already tried the type `SomeInterface[string]`, but I think that only works when the interface has a key/index signature defined, not specific properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all possible keys of [Mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) by `keyof`

```
type Keys = keyof SomeInterface;
```

Get all possible values of Mapped type by [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

```
type Values = SomeInterface[keyof SomeInterface];
```

Comment: Woow, thank you so much. That was quick and a very easy fix! It's hard to find this if you don't know the lingo for it yet.

Comment: Follow up question though: I tried the Values type already and it works on a small interface. Unfortunately, the interface I'm trying to apply it is way more complex, and for some reason, I get the type unknown returned. Any Ideas what the cause could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Please add another question with this interface and we will check out

Comment: Sure! Posted a question [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077208/typescript-indexed-access-operator-returns-type-unknown)